# Mask and smooth an image using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

The following code, as explained [here](https://www.learnopencv.com/filling-holes-in-an-image-using-opencv-python-c/), effectively finds the contours of an object in an image, and fills those contours with white, while setting the background to black.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
# Read image
im_in = cv2.imread('bee-02.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
th, im_th = cv2.threshold(im_in, 250, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
# Copy the thresholded image.
im_floodfill = im_th.copy()
# Mask used to flood filling.
h, w = im_th.shape[:2]
mask = np.zeros((h+2, w+2), np.uint8)
# Floodfill from point (0, 0)
cv2.floodFill(im_floodfill, mask, (0,0), 255)
# Invert floodfilled image
im_floodfill_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(im_floodfill)
# Combine the two images to get the foreground.
im_out = im_th | im_floodfill_inv
# Display images.
cv2.imshow("Foreground", im_out)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Here's an example of what it does:

[Image of a bee](http://weknowyourdreams.com/images/bee/bee-02.jpg) =>

[image]

What's a good way to augment the above code such that the exterior contours of the image are smoothed? If possible, I'd like to use a method that makes it possible to specify the gradation of the smoothing. I guess that one way to do it would be to apply heavy blurring before applying the masking function, but presumably, there's a better way.

Comment: define smooth contours... there is no trivial way that preserves fine detail like all those hairs and little spikes of the bee. are you willing to sacrifice that or not?

Comment: @Piglet - I'm following a working definition of "smooth" that's pretty much in line with people's understanding of what constitutes a smooth surface - that is, the hairs, spikes, etc., would be gone.

Comment: and should those fine details be "cut" off or rather be enclosed in the new smooth contour?

Answer (score 3):

I would look into [morphological opening and closing](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html) operations. Specifically I would try a morphological close with a nice big disc operator and you'll probably get something close to what you want.

They will operate directly on the binary data you've got (much less expensive than blurring) and will likely achieve the effect you're looking for in terms of simplifying or "blurring" the visual outline.

Comment: I'm trying the MORPH_CLOSE operation, and it's turning out pretty grainy. I'll try to experiment with the kernel, and see how that works out. Or is it likely that some sort of anti-aliasing will need to be applied after MORPH_CLOSE?

Comment: Use a larger kernel for the operation. In the craziest case if you use a disc kernel that's around the size of your entire image you should end up with a giant circle -- so somewhere in between that and what you have now should be a good balance.

Answer (score 1):

You can also make gaussian blur with large kernel (something like 7x7 or 15x15) before thresholding.